# How to safely minify Angular 2 Typescript application with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, angular, systemjs

How Angular 2 application can be safely minified for production?

The application is using SystemJS for module loader and also it's configured to use **gulp-typescript** for Typescript compile operation.

Here is the Gulp task configuration which is used for minification:

```
gulp.task('min:js', ['compile:ts'], function () {
return gulp.src([
    './node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
    './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
    './node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
    './node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
    './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
    './node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
    './node_modules/angular2/core.js',
    './node_modules/angular2/http.js',
    './node_modules/angular2/router.js',
    './node_modules/material-design-lite/material.js',

    './app/**/*.js',
    '!./app/' + packageName + '.min.js'])
.pipe(concat(packageName + '.js'))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(rename({
    suffix: '.min'
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./app/'));
});
```

the result of this task is nonsafe minified code which is causing:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

The SystemJS configuration in index.html is:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/[package name here]')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

and with files loaded separately in the order they are added in the gulp task the application is working correctly.

Comment: are you sure your typescript compiler is set up to produce ES5 JavaScript?

Comment: Yes it's producing ES5 JavaScript which as I said earlier is working perfectly without minification.